# Sklearn Pipeline: Get feature names after OneHotEncode In ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I want to get feature names after I fit the pipeline.

```
categorical_features = ['brand', 'category_name', 'sub_category']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
    
numeric_features = ['num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])
```

Then

```
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('regressor', GradientBoostingRegressor())])
```

After fitting with pandas dataframe, I can get feature importances from

`clf.steps[1][1].feature_importances_`

and I tried `clf.steps[0][1].get_feature_names()` but I got an error

```
AttributeError: Transformer num (type Pipeline) does not provide get_feature_names.
```

How can I get feature names from this?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can access the feature_names using the following snippet:

```
clf.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers_[1][1]\
   .named_steps['onehot'].get_feature_names(categorical_features)
```

Using sklearn >= 0.21 version, we can make it even simpler:

```
clf['preprocessor'].transformers_[1][1]\
    ['onehot'].get_feature_names(categorical_features)
```

Reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.DataFrame({'brand': ['aaaa', 'asdfasdf', 'sadfds', 'NaN'],
                   'category': ['asdf', 'asfa', 'asdfas', 'as'],
                   'num1': [1, 1, 0, 0],
                   'target': [0.2, 0.11, 1.34, 1.123]})

numeric_features = ['num1']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_features = ['brand', 'category']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('regressor',  LinearRegression())])
clf.fit(df.drop('target', 1), df['target'])

clf.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers_[1][1]\
   .named_steps['onehot'].get_feature_names(categorical_features)

# ['brand_NaN' 'brand_aaaa' 'brand_asdfasdf' 'brand_sadfds' 'category_as'
#  'category_asdf' 'category_asdfas' 'category_asfa']
```

Comment: how does one correctly match the feature importances with ALL the feature names (numeric + categorical)? Especially with OHE(handle_unknown='ignore').

Comment: @Paul In my case, I have combined df.columns with feature_names after that I removed categorical_features from the name list then combined it with feature_importances_.

Comment: exactly, but how do you make sure they are *combined in the right order*, so that they match up with the vector of feature importances? Seems not straighforward, would appreciate elegant code snippets

Comment: The combining order would be same as the pipeline steps. Hence we can find the exact order of the features. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534118/6347629 answer might be of use for you

Comment: So `StandardScaler()` does not have `get_feature_names()` . Do we have to combine the field names of numeric ones and one hot encoded ones later? Is there any other API that could provide us with the full feature names?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528350/can-you-consistently-keep-track-of-column-labels-using-sklearns-transformer-api/57534118#57534118 might give some clarity.

Comment: I am curious if the sequence of your pipeline matters.  For example I derived my `plot_names` using this process, but would like validation this is correct.  The feature importance plot looks intuitive.  `plot_names = pipeline.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers_[0][2] + list(pipeline.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers_[1][1].get_feature_names(categorical_feature_indexes))`

Comment: Use `get_feature_names_out()` instead of `get_feature_names()`

Answer (score 37):

Scikit-Learn 1.0 now has new features to keep track of feature names.

```
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# SimpleImputer does not have get_feature_names_out, so we need to add it
# manually. This should be fixed in Scikit-Learn 1.0.1: all transformers will
# have this method.
# g
SimpleImputer.get_feature_names_out = (lambda self, names=None:
                                       self.feature_names_in_)

num_pipeline = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(), StandardScaler())
transformer = make_column_transformer(
    (num_pipeline, ["age", "height"]),
    (OneHotEncoder(), ["city"]))
pipeline = make_pipeline(transformer, LinearRegression())



df = pd.DataFrame({"city": ["Rabat", "Tokyo", "Paris", "Auckland"],
                   "age": [32, 65, 18, 24],
                   "height": [172, 163, 169, 190],
                   "weight": [65, 62, 54, 95]},
                  index=["Alice", "Bunji", "Cécile", "Dave"])



pipeline.fit(df, df["weight"])


## get pipeline feature names
pipeline[:-1].get_feature_names_out()


## specify feature names as your columns
pd.DataFrame(pipeline[:-1].transform(df),
             columns=pipeline[:-1].get_feature_names_out(),
             index=df.index)
```

Comment: For me this results in Estimator encoder does not provide get_feature_names_out. Did you mean to call pipeline[:-1].get_feature_names_out()?

Comment: @AndiAnderle get_feature_names_out is not implemented on all estimators, see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21308 , I am using pipeline[:-1] to select only the column transformers step.

Comment: That's exactly what I do (pipeline[0].get_feature_names_out()). pipeline[0] is my ColumnTransformer with OrdinalEncoder and SimpleImputer. Still says the above mentioned error.

Comment: Are you sure that you have Scikit-Learn 1.0 version ?

Comment: Yes. 1.0.1… really srange..

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so please share I'm interested: I'm trying to do the same thing. OrdinalEncoder a pipeline with imputer and ordinal encoder, and I need to keep track of the feature names after fitting

Comment: `SimpleImputer` doesn't have the function `get_feature_names_out`, unless you're using the nightly sklearn build.

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: actually Peter's comment answer is in the [ColumnTransformer doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

> The order of the columns in the transformed feature matrix follows the order of how the columns are specified in the transformers list. Columns of the original feature matrix that are not specified are dropped from the resulting transformed feature matrix, unless specified in the passthrough keyword. Those columns specified with passthrough are added at the right to the output of the transformers.

---

To complete Venkatachalam's answer with what Paul asked in his comment, the order of feature names as it appears in the ColumnTransformer .get_feature_names() method depends on the order of declaration of the steps variable at the ColumnTransformer instanciation.

I could not find any doc so I just played with the toy example below and that let me understand the logic.

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

class testEstimator(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.string = string

    def fit(self,X):
        return self

    def transform(self,X):
        return np.full(X.shape, self.string).reshape(-1,1)

    def get_feature_names(self):
        return self.string

transformers = [('first_transformer',testEstimator('A'),1), ('second_transformer',testEstimator('B'),0)]
column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers)
steps = [('scaler',RobustScaler()), ('transformer', column_transformer)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

dt_test = np.zeros((1000,2))
pipeline.fit_transform(dt_test)

for name,step in pipeline.named_steps.items():
    if hasattr(step, 'get_feature_names'):
        print(step.get_feature_names())
```

For the sake of having a more representative example I added a RobustScaler and nested the ColumnTransformer on a Pipeline. By the way, you will find my version of Venkatachalam's way to get the feature name looping of the steps. You can turn it into a slightly more usable variable by unpacking the names with a list comprehension:

```py
[i for i in v.get_feature_names() for k, v in pipeline.named_steps.items() if hasattr(v,'get_feature_names')]
```

So play around with the dt_test and the estimators to soo how the feature name is built, and how it is concatenated in the get_feature_names().
Here is another example with a transformer which output 2 columns, using the input column:

```py
class testEstimator3(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,string):
        self.string = string

    def fit(self,X):
        self.unique = np.unique(X)[0]
        return self

    def transform(self,X):
        return np.concatenate((X.reshape(-1,1), np.full(X.shape,self.string).reshape(-1,1)), axis = 1)

    def get_feature_names(self):
        return list((self.unique,self.string))

dt_test2 = np.concatenate((np.full((1000,1),'A'),np.full((1000,1),'B')), axis = 1)

transformers = [('first_transformer',testEstimator3('A'),1), ('second_transformer',testEstimator3('B'),0)]
column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers)
steps = [('transformer', column_transformer)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

pipeline.fit_transform(dt_test2)
for step in pipeline.steps:
    if hasattr(step[1], 'get_feature_names'):
        print(step[1].get_feature_names())
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for how to access column names after successive pipelines with the last one being `ColumnTransformer`, you can access them by following this example here:

In the `full_pipeline` there are two pipelines `gender` and `relevent_experience`

```
full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("gender", gender_encoder, ["gender"]),
    ("relevent_experience", relevent_experience_encoder, ["relevent_experience"]),
])
```

The `gender` pipeline looks like this:

```
gender_encoder = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder())
])
```

After fitting the `full_pipeline`, you can access the column names using the following snippet

```
full_pipeline.transformers_[0][1][1].get_feature_names_out()
```

In my case the output was:
`array(['x0_Female', 'x0_Male', 'x0_Other'], dtype=object)`

Comment: this does not work for me since i get AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute 'transformers_'

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to getting this right. After you build your pipeline:

```
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                  ('regressor', DecisionTreeRegressor())])
```

Fit `clf` onto the `features` and the `target` variable as follows:

```
clf.fit(features, target)
```

and you should be then able to access feature names for `OneHotEncoder`:

```
clf.named_steps['preprocessor'].transformers_[1][1].named_steps['onehot'].get_feature_names_out()
```