# Is there a way to get the names of features processed with MaxAbsScaler and OneHotEncoder for plotting Shapley values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shap

I am trying to use Shapley summary_plot to inspect the top twenty features in my Random Forest classifier. First, I preprocessed my data with MaxAbsScaler and OneHotEncoder using make_pipeline and ColumnTransformer. When I plot the Shapley values I see that all of the feature names are numbers and I cannot figure out how to correctly identify the feature names. I have referenced: [Sklearn Pipeline: Get feature names after OneHotEncode In ColumnTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646709/sklearn-pipeline-get-feature-names-after-onehotencode-in-columntransformer) but I see the error message below.

**First I try the Shapley plot:**

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test_scaled)

#convert X_test_scaled to DF so can call column names
X_test_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_test_scaled)
X_test_scaled.head()
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, features=X_test_scaled, feature_names = X_test_scaled.columns)
```

produces:
[Shapley summary plot with numbered features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iAaT.png)

**Then to get names, I tried from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646709/sklearn-pipeline-get-feature-names-after-onehotencode-in-columntransformer):**

```
preprocess['maxabsscaler'].transformers_[1][1]['onehotencoder']\
                   .get_feature_names(categorical_features)
```

### which outputs:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2                    #.get_feature_names(categorical_features
3
----> 4 preprocess['maxabsscaler'].transformers_[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iAaT.png)['onehotencoder']
5                    .get_feature_names(categorical_features)

TypeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Can  you simplify this example a bit and add a [minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) `MaxAbsScaler` should not alter the number of features, but `OneHotEncoder` will introduce a new feature for each unique value in a column: do you have a way you want to name these? (e.g. `blood_pressure_category_1`, `blood_pressure_category2`, etc.)