# Get names of most important features for classification after transformation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a classification problem in Python. I want to find out what are the most important features for classification.
My data is mixed, some columns are categorical values some are not categorical.
I'm applying transformations with `OneHotEncoder` and `Normalizer`:

```
columns_for_vectorization = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
columns_for_normalization = ['F', 'G', 'H']

transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('Vector Cat', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = "ignore"), columns_for_vectorization),
                                                        ('Normalizer', Normalizer(), columns_for_normalization)],
                                          remainder='passthrough') # Default is to drop untransformed columns
```

After that I'm splitting my data and I'm doing transformation:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, results, test_size = 0.25, random_state=0)

x_train = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = transformerVectoriser.transform(x_test)
```

Then, Im training my model:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 5, n_estimators = 50, random_state = 0)
model = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

And I'm printing the best features:

```
print(model.feature_importances_)
```

I'm getting results like this:

```
[1.40910562e-03 1.46133832e-03 4.05058130e-03 3.92205197e-03
 2.13243521e-03 5.78555893e-03 1.51927254e-03 1.14987114e-03
 ...
 6.37840204e-04 7.21061812e-04 5.77726129e-04 5.32382587e-04]
```

The problem is, that in beginning, I had 8 features, but because of the transformation, I have more than 20 features (because of the categorical data)
How can I handle this?
How can I know what beginning feature is the most important?

Comment: Have you tried this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646709/sklearn-pipeline-get-feature-names-after-onehotencode-in-columntransformer

Comment: That answer shows how to access it if I have transformer and classifier in pipeline. How can I do it in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to get the names of features that were treated by 'Vector Cat' transformer:

```
VectorCatNames = list(transformerVectoriser.transformers_[0][1]['Vector Cat'].get_feature_names(columns_for_vectorization))
```

Then, names of your final features can be saved as:

```
feature_names = VectorCatNames + columns_for_normalization
```

Comment: Im getting this error: 
OneHotEncoder' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

This [github gist](https://gist.github.com/Per48edjes/f211dc1e1b65c12c47a3d6055a43b3de) seems to say you can get the columns after fit/transform with:

```py
numeric_features = X.select_dtypes(np.number).columns

enc_cat_features = transformerVectorizer.named_transformers_['Vector cat'].get_feature_names()
labels = np.concatenate([numeric_features, enc_cat_features])
transformed_df_X = pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.transform(X_train).toarray(), columns=labels)
# To access your data - transformed_df_X
# To access your columns - transformed_df_X.columns
```

If you can't seem to get it working through the ColumnTransformer due to 'subscriptable' errors, you can *definitely* do this directly on the OneHotEncoder object.

Typically I also mess with the names afterwards because OneHotEncoder gives ugly automatic names.

Anyway then once you can access the `X.columns` thing, you can do whatever you like with the feature importances. My sample code for plotting them with the feature names uses `permutation_importance` instead but apparently `feature_importance` gives the same structure so you might have some luck and this will work for you.

```
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_feature_importance(model, X_train, y_train, feature_names):
   result = permutation_importance(model, X_train, y_train, n_repeats=10)
   perm_sorted_idx = result.importances_mean.argsort()

   fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(5, 15))
   ax2.boxplot(result.importances[perm_sorted_idx].T, vert=False,
               labels=feature_names[perm_sorted_idx])
   fig.tight_layout()
   plt.show()
```

On the UCI ML horse colic set with a random forest, this gave me an output image with the categorical & numerical names like this:

[image: Box plot showing features AbdomenClass4, RectTemp, AbdominalDistension3, CapillaryRefillTime1, PeripheralPulse3 as key features]