# Sklearn: Extract feature names after model fitting with polynomialFeature, onehot encoding and OrdinalEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-engineering

As suggested in many other posts [e.g.,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646709/sklearn-pipeline-get-feature-names-after-onehotencode-in-columntransformer)

there are ways of extracting relevant feature names. However, How do I make sure that feature names align/are in the same order as the `model.coef_`?

The structure I have is like:

```
num1_pre = Pipeline([ ... ])
num2_pre = Pipeline([ ... ])

cat1_pre = Pipeline([("cat_encode", OneHotEncoder())])
cat2_pre = Pipeline([("cat_encode", OrdinalEncoder()) ])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num1_pre", num1_pre, num_col1), 
    ("num2_pre", num2_pre, num_col2), 
    ("cat1_pre", cat1_pre, cat_col1), 
    ("cat2_pre", cat2_pre, cat_col2)
])

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
    ("poly_features", PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only=True, include_bias=False)),
    ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
    ("model", LinearRegression())
])
```

My first attempt is to make use of the `get_feature_names_out()`. I have used CV do obtain a *good* model:

```
model = grid_search.best_estimator_
model[:-2].get_feature_names_out()
```

returns **input_features is not equal to feature_names_in_**